writers.pgpointcloud: Missing value for positional argument 'filename'
I am following this to populate point clouds data in postgres DB.
My input json is:
[
    {
        "type":"readers.las",
        "filename":"D:\\.......\\input.las",
        "spatialreference":"EPSG:26916"
    },
    {
        "type":"filters.chipper",
        "capacity":400
    },
    {
        "type":"writers.pgpointcloud",
        "connection":"host='localhost' dbname='Lidar' user='postgres' password='postgres' port='5432'",
        "table":"my_pointcloud",
        "compression":"dimensional",
        "srid":"26916"
    }
]

But command:
pdal pipeline --input mypipeline.json

...gives error:
PDAL: writers.pgpointcloud: Missing value for positional argument 'filename'.

I dont see any such argument for writers.pgpointcloud in official documentation.
What am I missing?
